# Does Gall break Cho's stealth?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

If Cho is put into stealth by either Tyrande's ult or Medivh's level 20 talent, does Gall casting an ability break the stealth?

Comment: I can't answer that, but I know stealth is *not* broken in a very similar situation: when Abathur has a Symbiote on a permamently-cloaked heroes (Zeratul, Nova), he *can* cast abilities all day long without breaking stealth (as seen in several months worth of gameplay highlights).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't break the stealth. Cho and Gall are considered **different units in terms of damage dealing**, as you might've seen in the score screen. It is the same interaction as when Abathur uses Symbiote on a stealthed Hero - he can attack freely while the Hero remains stealthed.

As a result, any action that will usually break the stealth / dismount a Hero cannot happen/will not interrupt if it is performed by Gall, since the body considered is Cho. For example, Gall's level 1 talent, *Nudge*, cannot be performed if Cho is mounted, as such a movement will normally dismount a Hero. However, Gall can still use all of his Basic and Heroic Abilities without dismounting or breaking stealth in this case.